# Can anyone tell me the coding snippet and the exact files for the dspace 4.x sidebar facet search?

Tags: xml, xslt, dspace

When we are clicking in any item of Discovery sidebar facet,which files are calling? Can anyone tell me the exact file names and code snippet?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using XMLUI...

When you click on a link, your request is routed to /discover.

The Cocoon sitemap.xmap includes the following rule that matches "discover".

https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-xmlui/src/main/resources/aspects/Discovery/sitemap.xmap#L112-L123

Which maps SimpleSearch to the following class

https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-xmlui/src/main/resources/aspects/Discovery/sitemap.xmap#L26

Which invokes code in

https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-xmlui/src/main/java/org/dspace/app/xmlui/aspect/discovery/SimpleSearch.java